# Calayer subclass problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calayer

I am creating calayer subclass for carousel view.

My subclass is

> @interface Carousellayer : CALayer {
>
> }
> I get an error message in

Cannot find interface declaration for 'CALayer', superclass of 'Carousellayer' in Carousellayer.h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CALayer header files are not included by default, you need to import QuartzCore:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

And also link your application with the corresponding framework.